# Are there any functions where differentiating the Taylor series yields an accurate approximation for the differentiated function?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Considering the Taylor series for $e^x$, you can differentiate it and get the same series. ie $$\frac{d}{dx} (1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + ...) = 1 + x + ...$$

This is obviously a property of $e^x$, thus implying that differentiating the Taylor series yields the series for the differentiated function. Is this a valid property, or just a fluke because it's $e^x$? And does this hold true for other functions with Taylor series--can you differentiate other series and still get an accurate representation of the differentiated function? If you can explain the underlying analysis that would be very helpful too.

Thanks :)

Comment: You can always differentiate term-by-term under suitable conditions, see Theorem 2 here: https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~agk22/uniform.pdf

Comment: *Why* is it not true for any other function? And I'm not saying the derivative of the series has to yield the same series for the other functions, I'm just saying it has to yield an accurate approximation.

Comment: I've edited my comment because I misunderstood your question (I thought you wanted to obtain the same series) Please read it again

Comment: You seem to be asking for what functions $f(x)$ does $\frac{df}{dx}=f(x)$ for all values of $x$. The solution $f(x)=Ce^x$ is the only solution to this differential equation. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27929/how-to-find-fx-if-dfx-dx-fx.

Comment: @sammy gerbil no that is not what I’m asking

Comment: Well can you please be clearer about what you are asking? You refer to *an accurate approximation* but that is too vague without defining what you mean by *accurate* and over what range of $x$ you require this level of accuracy. The higher the accuracy you demand and the broader the range, then $f(x) \to Ce^x$.

Comment: @sammy gerbil see the upvoted answer, it’s what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n, x\in (-r,r),$ then

$$f'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_nx^{n-1}, x\in (-r,r).$$

This is a standard result in the theory of Taylor series.